# C: What will the statement 'return A || 1' return when A >1?

Tags: c, objective-c

Although I wouldn't have written it myself, what is the expected result of the following statement where `A` (guaranteed to zero or positive integer) is greater than 1?

`return A || 1;`

In many languages, I would expect `A` to be returned, unless the value of `A` is zero, in which case 1 would be.

I don't have my C book to hand, but I note that in reality, the value 1 always seems to be returned. Is this a result of compiler optimisation or given the potential ambiguity of the expression, is it that the return value is non-deterministic?

Comment: Does it not return "YES", which is then converted to 1 if you try to get it as an int? I've no clue about Objective C, I'm just guessing here. (A quick google told me that YES is Objective C's 'True'.)

Comment: Not quite... `YES` in Objective-C is just a macro giving `1`. So, it just returns `1`. No conversion to `bool` (or `BOOL` or `_Bool` or whatever) is involved.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `return A ? A : 1;`

Comment: That's exactly what I changed it to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard says

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0.   The result has type int.

See section 6.5.14 of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @Roger: Note that if you want the alternate effect you described, you can get that with `return A ? A : 1;`

Answer (score 3):

The expected result is YES (or true)

`||` operator returns true value if at least one of its operands is true (2nd operand in your code is obviously true)

Comment: Doh! Of course. I think all the rain has turned my brain to mush this afternoon. I was trying to explain it to someone else after I fixed the bug and was too hung up on the value of the numbers.

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with any #defines of `true` or `YES` but only with the result of the expression which is of type int. In this case always 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is straight C (no Objective-C involved). It will always return 1.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the result of `||`, `&&`, or `!` is always `0` or `1`, never any other non-zero value, regardless of the values of the operands. That means your `A || 1` will always yield 1.

Answer (score 0):

with C-based languages any nonzero value is true(represented by 1). And if your A is zero it will check the other comparisons if it's an OR comparison

Suffice to say, in your example, whatever the value of A is, will always return 1 even if you are using || 2. with 2 being nonzero, when performed with logical operator OR, will always return true(represented by 1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the compiler will optimize and not even examine the value of A.  Can someone confirm? I was under the impression that with A&&0, A||1, and A||0 (=A&&1), the compiler saves time by recognizing that the expression can be simplified to 0, 1, or A respectively.